# MongoDB doesn't update the object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I have a problem with MongoDB not updating edited data. I know that the id passed is working because is the same in both my browser console and my server console. I have tried everything and nothing seams to be working.

```
app.put('/contactlist/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
  db.contactlist.findAndModify({
    query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
    update: {$set: {"name": req.body.name, "email": req.body.email, "number": req.body.number}},
    upsert: true}, function (err, doc) {
      res.json(doc);
    }
  );
});
```

in console after put and then get request

```
    { _id: '592de1421d4fff0614bfc884',
  name: 'Adamie',
  email: 'adam.michnik@kurwa.pl',
  number: '666 666 666' }
i recived the get request
[ { _id: 592de1421d4fff0614bfc884,
    name: 'Adaś',
    email: 'adam.michnik@kurwa.pl',
    number: '666 666 666' },
  { _id: 592de19f1d4fff0614bfc887,
    name: 'Józio',
    email: 'dżunga.szwili@cccp.ussr',
    number: '444 444 444' } ]
```

Comment: What is `mongojs` ?

Comment: @loan node module that lets doing stuff to db

Comment: Do you mean `doc` is the unchanged document? If so, did you check in the MongoDB console if it's not actually updated?

Comment: Could you try and split it up? First find and then update?

Comment: @robertklep it's the same and i was doing checking

Comment: By default, `findAndModify` will return the old (unchanged) document, but it should have been updated in the database. I assume that `req.body` also contains valid data?

Comment: @robertklep yeah i was checking everything. console.log(req.body) returns changed object

Comment: See the [documentation](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) There is a `findAndModify()` example on there and it has the `new: true` option that is notably missing from your code. Show what `req.body` looks like in your question.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what myself and robert are asking. Please show us a `console.log(req.body)`. Probably to JSON stringify as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn its the first object

Comment: Okay got that. Your response is an "array" though. That is not possible with `findAndModify()`. That response must be coming from other code not listed here.

Comment: @NeilLunn I think he means that he also has a `GET` route that will retrieve all contacts (which is showing that the `PUT` didn't change the `name` property)